# Why doesn't just a variable name display the variable in a script, like in the interpreter?

Tags: python, printing, interpreter

I want to display a string which is `return`ed by a function in a Python script, without using `print`:

```
def myfunc(mystring):
    return "Converting to lowercase :{0}".format(mystring.lower())

result=myfunc("LOWER")
result
```

But it doesn't give an output. How can I get `result` to display without `print`?

Comment: That is print's job. What is the reason that you don't want to use print? If there is a rule, use `sys.stdout.write`. You can't make Python write return values, just the command line interpreter does.

Comment: Why do you think you can or need to produce output without `print`?  If this is homework; and you're having a hard time figuring out how to satisfy the requirements; post the actual text of the assignment, and we will help you to interpret it.

Comment: Why would you expect to see anything without a print?  The interpreter (at the `>>>` prompt, prints as a convenience to help you.  Nowhere else does Python print automagically.  Is that want you want?  A script that prints automagically?

Comment: Without using `print`? It works only in interactive interpreter. Or you can use `sys.stdout.write` but that would be the same thing.

Comment: By "trying", do you mean "typing into the interpreted" or "saving into a .py file and then running"?  And why don't you want to use print, if you're trying to print something?

Comment: Ok,the problem was that i was running the .py script.I didn't knew that its not the same as running from the interpreter.

Comment: George, please remember to format your code when you post a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does print `'Converting to lowercase :lower'` when run in an interactive session (using `python` or `ipython`).

It does not, however, print anything if run as part of a script, since there is no implicit printing of expression results.

This is how it's meant to be.

If you want to print something from a script, use `print` or `sys.stdout.write()`.

Comment: @George _What_ is it? What was the specific part of the answer you were looking for? Please update your question to make it clearer (I don't mean add the answer to the question, just edit it so it can be _helpful to others in the future_) by more directly stating what it is you need, and preferably why.

Comment: @agf:I don't have a specific reason.I just didn't want to use print.As i said above the code runs ok form the interpreter but not from a .py script.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to print:

```
sys.stdout.write()
```